# Configuring MAAS with vmware esxi nodes and virsh

Tags: virtualization, maas, vmware

I have configured a MAAS Server and my nodes are VMWare ESXi hosted virtual machines. I have installed libvirt-bin package on MAAS and I have tested the ESX connection from MAAS to my host:

```
$ virsh -c esx://root@10.238.254.251/?no_verify=1 list --all
```

The command gives me tha list of virtual machines on ESXi host 10.238.254.251.

Then I power up a new VM and is shown on MAAS as a new machine, but when I configure it with Virsh it indicates any of theses errors:

No rack controllers can access the BMC of node: OStackPR-CloudCtrl

or

Cannot login to virsh console

I configured Power Type in the following way:

> Power type: Virsh (virtual systems)
>   Power address: esx://root@10.238.254.251/?no_verify=1
>   Power ID: OStackPR-CloudCtrl (name of VM on ESXi host)
>   Power password: ******** (password for root on ESXi host)

What am I missing? It's strange that virsh connection from console is working and not from MAAS GUI.

thank you in advance....

Jorge

Comment: MAAS can talk directly to an ESXi instance with the Vpshere power type. Have you tried that power type as well? That might help resolve the issue. If not does the /var/log/maas/rackd.log provide any helpful information?

Comment: vSphere power type? Do you mean VMWare power type? If so, I thought that type was for VMWare Workstations on chassis...

Comment: Here you have the regiond.log file when I set up the virsh power type:

Comment: Sorry, how I attach the log?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
esx://root@10.238.254.251/?no_verify=1
```

try to use

```
esx://root@10.238.254.251/system?no_verify=1
```